# Why can't node.js connect to my Database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, vagrant

I'm trying to run node.js on my Vagrant virtual box. When I try to connect node.js to my database, it fails as shown below. Can anyone explain to me how I should fix it?

```
% sequelize -m
Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".
You need to install mysql package manually

TypeError: Cannot call method 'createConnection' of undefined
    at module.exports.connect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:259:28)
    at Object.pool.Pooling.Pool.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:125:19)
    at createResource (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:258:13)
    at dispense (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:250:9)
    at Object.me.acquire (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:316:5)
    at module.exports.enqueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:312:19)
    at module.exports.ConnectorManager.query (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connector-manager.js:164:15)
    at module.exports.Sequelize.query (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:252:34)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-interface.js:689:32)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:26:18)
```

I can guarantee that my DB is up and running and connectable:

```
% mysql -u root -pmyPassWord


Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 45
Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
mysql>
```

I can also show you that I have installed the mysql package using npm:

```
% sudo npm install -g mysql@2.0.0-alpha8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql/2.0.0-alpha8
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql/2.0.0-alpha8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bignumber.js/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bignumber.js/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
mysql@2.0.0-alpha8 /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.22/lib/node_modules/mysql
├── require-all@0.0.3
└── bignumber.js@1.0.1

% sudo npm install -g mysql
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bignumber.js/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bignumber.js/1.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/require-all/0.0.3
mysql@2.0.0-rc2 /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.22/lib/node_modules/mysql
├── require-all@0.0.3
└── bignumber.js@1.0.1
```

Comment: Your DB is running, but your MySQL package isn't set up correctly. (Hence the "You need to install mysql package manually"). I've never experienced that, but that's definitely your issue.

Comment: If I've successfully installed the node.js mysql module using npm as shown above, why is it saying the MySQL package isn't set up correctly? Seems like it should be.

Comment: I agree. I don't know why it's saying that. But it's clearly saying that for a reason, and that's where the issue is happening. My guess is it's something to do with your system and limitations it may put on the MySQL library or Node itself.

Comment: Have you tried gutting your node install and starting fresh with a source-built copy (using make, etc.)?

Comment: @r3mus No, I have not tried that. Sounds painful and possibly error prone. I'm concerned I might go backwards and things that are working now might stop working. I'm on Ubuntu. Usually I install things using "sudo apt-get install"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
The issue was the node was looking for its modules in /usr/local/lib/node_modules
but npm was installing them in ~/.nvm/v0.10.22/lib/node_modules.

So I replaced /usr/local/lib/node_modules with a soft link to ~/.nvm/v0.10.22/lib/node_modules